# HTML DOM Area Object / Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tried to create this map area, but it doesn't work. Does someone know the solution? Thanks

html:

```
<html>
<body>  
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>logo</td>
            <td>description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <map id ="first" name="Homepage"></map>         
                <script src="appendChild.js"></script>      
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
    var start= document.createElement("AREA");
    start.setAttribute("href", "Homepage.html");
    start.setAttribute("src" , "Homepage.jpg");
    start.setAttribute("shape", "rect");
    start.setAttribute("coords", "18,131,113,140");

    document.getElementById("first").appendChild(start);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an element (usually an `<img>`) with the [`usemap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-usemap) attribute set to `#` + [the `<map>` element's `name` value]. In your case, you'd need to have an `<img src="Homepage.jpg" usemap="#Homepage" />`.

**EDIT:** You can add that `<img>` dynamically, too.

```js
var start = document.createElement("AREA"),
  image = document.createElement("IMG");

start.setAttribute("href", "Homepage.html");
start.setAttribute("shape", "rect");
start.setAttribute("coords", "18,131,113,140");

image.setAttribute("src", "//placekitten.com/221/221");
image.setAttribute("usemap", "#Homepage");

document.getElementById("first").appendChild(image);
document.getElementById("first").appendChild(start);
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>logo</td>
    <td>description</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <map id="first" name="Homepage"></map>
      <script src="appendChild.js"></script>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ok thank you, but I think the DOM Area won't help me further for my solution. Because I want to create one html file and one js file where the whole map dynamic is.

Comment: You could dynamically create that `<img>` the same way you are creating the `<area>` tag. That would allow you to do all of the image mapping in JS. I updated the code snippet to illustrate that usage.

Comment: How can I add more map areas calling the same html file but different pictures ? That I only use one html file and js file ? ^^

Comment: That depends on your use case. How many images/maps/areas you need to create? And how frequently you'll have to change/update them?

Comment: But your function can`t add more pictures with different areas. They should all reference to the same html file. Example: Homepage.html What I try to say it that the pictures don't change dynamically  associated with the according area.

Comment: Right. I was trying to gauge the complexity of your use case before suggesting a solution. It sounds like you have a number of images with associated (possibly unique) mapped areas that you want to inject into the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) via JavaScript.

Comment: You could collect all of the unique image, name, coordinate data in an `Array` or JSON Object. Then build a function — using what you already have written, modified to use the Array/JSON data instead of your hardcoded values, to inject your new image, map, and area elements into the DOM. Then write a `for` loop to iterate through the Array/JSON, calling your new injection function for each group of values. [This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/itopizarro/0wys30n4/) is a simplified example.

Comment: … which is, basically, a custom JavaScript template pattern. Once you have the salient data collected as JSON, though, you could easily use one of the many existing JS template libraries ([Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/), [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/),[Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#template), et cetera).